# Find value of column based on another column condition (max) in polars for many columns

Tags: python, python-polars

If I have this dataframe:

```
pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 1, 2, 3], y=[5, 2, 3, 3],z=[4,7,8,2]))
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 5   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

and I want to find the value in x where y is max, then again find the value in x where z is max, and repeat for hundreds more columns so that I end up with something like:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬─────────┐
│ column ┆ x_value │
│ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str    ┆ i64     │
╞════════╪═════════╡
│ y      ┆ 0       │
│ z      ┆ 2       │
└────────┴─────────┘
```

or

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ y   ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

What is the best polars way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform a "wide to long" reshape with [`.melt()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt)

```py
df.melt("x", variable_name="column")
```

```py
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬───────┐
│ x   ┆ column ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ y      ┆ 5     │
│ 1   ┆ y      ┆ 2     │
│ 2   ┆ y      ┆ 3     │
│ 3   ┆ y      ┆ 3     │
│ 0   ┆ z      ┆ 4     │
│ 1   ┆ z      ┆ 7     │
│ 2   ┆ z      ┆ 8     │
│ 3   ┆ z      ┆ 2     │
└─────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Then `.filter` the max value per column.

```py
(df.melt("x", variable_name="column")
   .filter(
     pl.col("value") == pl.col("value").max().over("column")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬───────┐
│ x   ┆ column ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ y      ┆ 5     │
│ 2   ┆ z      ┆ 8     │
└─────┴────────┴───────┘
```